# How does a Windows process memory dump look like

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, assembly, process

I just try to understand the structure of a memory layout for a process in Windows, so this is my main goal.

I thought it looks like this:

[image: prossesMemoryLayout]

But then I read that processes under Windows *can* have multiple stacks - is this true?

Furthermore, I found a small program which should correspond to the picture above.

[image: process Memory Layout Prog]

But it did not!
The result is:

Prog 00411145

Data 00417160

Heap 00706D90

Stack 0018FF38

Increment the heapPointer: 00706D91

Increment the heapPointer: 00706D92

but what I got from the disassembly window in visual studio was:

[image: Disassambly Process Memory Layout prog]

Except for the main entrance I do not see any addresses corresponding.

Does anyone has a good explanation, or a **good** tutorial which covers this topic and answers my questions.

I also do not understand the linker map file, maybe this can make things stand a reason.

Comment: You should break your question into several questions.

Comment: *But than i read that processes on windows can have multiple stacks? Is this true.* Each thread has a stack, and each process can have multiple threads.

Comment: I thought more like :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640344/how-many-heaps-have-a-software-at-least-under-windows

Comment: The Windows memory manager is a lot more advanced than you assume.  Get insight from reading "Windows Internals" and by using the SysInternals' VMMap utility.